# mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/vtiger/includes/runtime/Viewer.php

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, mkdir, vtiger

I am trying to install `vtiger 6` on my `ubuntu` system on `apache` server.

I am getting a **error** while running it :

> Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/vtiger/includes/runtime/Viewer.php on line 58
>
> Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/vtiger/includes/runtime/Viewer.php on line 58

I changed the main folder "vtiger" permission 777 bt its still issue can someone help me??

Answer (score 8):

SSH to your server and do the following:

```
cd /var/www
chown -R www-data:www-data .
```

Make sure you run the chown command in the www folder or vtiger folder if you wish, it is really important that you do not run the command from the root, as it could be catastrophic. This should resolve your issue.

Comment: the chown command needs to be run by the root user. To do this as a non root user you will need to run the following command. `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .` again this needs to be run from the www directory.  Once you run the command you will prompted for the root password. Simply enter the password hit return and all done. If you don't have the root password then you are a bit screwed on this one.

Comment: Did the command execute or did you get operation not permitted again?

Comment: When you changed the permissions to 777 for vtiger did you change the permissions recursively or just for the vtiger folder only? If not I would recursively change all the folders to 777. Once everything is done, then follow the command on this link
https://forums.vtiger.com/viewtopic.php?t=34559 as 777 is obviously a security risk. Also did you make sure to add the "." at the end of the chown command?

Answer (score 0):

When you change the directory permissions to 777 for the /test directory this problem is solved.